# Escaping crashes my output

Tags: escaping

When I add wordpress escaping code like esc_attr_e to below variable, it writes text instead of html code to my browser:

```
   <?php echo esc_attr_e( $redux_demo['editor-text-header-left'], 'hekim' ); ?>
```

when I remove the escaping code, the variable gives html code.

now, it gives the below text:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-medkit text-thm2"></i> Help | </a><a href="#">Forum | </a><a href="#">Skype | </a><a href="#">Mon - Sat 9.00 - 19.00</a>
```

How can I escape it correctly?

Comment: It's doing what it's supposed to, `esc_attr` and `esc_attr_r` are for use inside attributes, There is no single escaping function, rather you have to use the one appropriate for your situation. Additionally, `esc_attr_e` is not shorthand for `echo esc_attr(` it's actually a part of the translation API aka `echo esc_attr( __(`, you should not be passing HTML strings into the translation APIs.

Comment: @TomJNowell I changed it to   <?php echo esc_html( $redux_demo['editor-text-header-left']); ?> but it still gives text.Can you give an example for this variable? I am new in escaping issues

Comment: The whole point of `esc_html` is to print text instead of HTML. If you want to allow any HTML, then it shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: `esc_html` isn't intended to print out HTML tags, it's for printing out text that shouldn't have HTML in it. As Jacob said, if you want to allow anything then it isn't possible to escape ( allowing anything means it's unescaped by definition ). Your HTML fragment is too complex too escape, and this is not the right location to do escaping, it's too high up the chain. Escaping needs to be granular, so don't escape a menu, escape the attributes on the tags, and the labels etc, not the whole thing all at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. `echo esc_attr_e` should be just `esc_attr_e`, the `_e` means it already echo's
2. `esc_attr_e` is not just an escaping function, it's a localisation API, it's shorthand for `echo esc_attr( __(`
3. `esc_attr` strips out HTML, it's intended for use inside HTML attributes where HTML tags are not allowed.
4. You must never pass variables and dynamic values into localisation functions

If you want to escape a string that contains basic HTML such as paragraphs etc, use `wp_kses_post`, e.g.:

```php
echo wp_kses_post( $redux_demo['editor-text-header-left'] );
```